# how do I make an icon (on the win 11 taskbar) that opens windows terminal as an ssh profile by default

Tags: ssh, taskbar, icons, windows-terminal

I have an icon on my task bar that opens a windows terminal to cmd.exe by default, and in the profile for windows terminal I also have an entry for doing ssh to a server that I connect to.  I would like an icon that instead of opening cmd.exe opens ssh without me selecting it from the dropdown menu.

Normally, most icons have a property menu that one can customize, but when I right click on the icon in the task bar for cmd.exe, it doesn't show me a "properties" entry nor a way to "copy" it.  It does show my ssh entry.

I did find the settings in terminal the let me make my ssh entry be the default to be opened, but how to make that a separate icon.  Not that I used cmd.exe that often, but I really want it to be a distinct icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shortcut on the desktop (right click->new->shortcut) and type in "wt --profile "<your profile name, with capitals>" in the "Type the location of the item" field.

Test this works (i.e. that you've got the correct profile name)!

Drag this to the taskbar. Viola!